# How to load content into div element with flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I'd like to fill / update a div area in index.html with the result from the python function, but I don't know how to do this. I know there are several other questions with a similar topic but I couldn't succeed with them because they were too specific. I'm pulling my hair out over this.

  Would be someone so nice and guide me? 
This is a function in main.py:

```
@app.route('/')
    
    def index():
        return render_template('index.html')
        
 @app.route('/stat/')
        
        def stat():
        
            a = 2
            b = 10
        
            return(str(a) + ' is not ' + str(b))
```

this is the index.html:

```
<body>

    <form action="/stat/"> 

    <button type="submit" id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">check stat</button>

    </form>

 <div id="stat_content"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: If you want to add something to a loaded web page you need JavaScript and AJAX on browser side.

Comment: Have a look here. You’ll need to pass the calculated `stat` value back into the template.  [This link uses similar logic](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates) with the example of a name.  You **do not** need js or AJAX for this simple task.

Comment: @Michael Butscher yes but I have no idea where to start with it. there are some tutorials but always with other purposes / structures which are only confusing me. Do you know where I can find a step by step tutorial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @S3DEV points out, you will need to pass the string to the template via an additional argument. For example, we might do something like this:

```py
@app.route('/stat/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) # EDIT
    def stat():
        a = 2
        b = 10
        text = f"{a} is not equal to {b}"
        return render_template("index.html", text=text)
```

In the code above, we set `text` to be the string to be passed to the template. In the template, we will be able to access this string variable as `text`.

Now when `index.html` is rendered, it will be looking for the `text` variable that is passed in from the Flask application. This is taken care of by [Jinja 2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com), which is the rendering engine used by Flask.

```html
<div id="stat_content">
  {% if text %}
  <h2>No text to show</h2>
  {% else %}
  <h2>{{ text }}</h2>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Using Jinja 2 syntax with curly braces, we first check if the `text` variable exists or not; if it does not exist, we render the message, "No text to show." This will happen when we first route into `"/"`, or the default home route of the Flask app.

Once the user fills out the form, however, they will be redirected to `"/stat/"`, at which point we will now have generated `text` and passed it back to `index.html` via the `render_template("index.html", text=text)` function call. Then, when Jinja 2 renders `index.html`, it will see that `text` was passed over from the Flask app and display that message, namely that 2 is not equal to 10.

Comment: I get an error: ´Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL´

Comment: @MarkT - Update the route to: `@app.route('/stat/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`.  This allows both the GET and POST request methods to access the function. The button press is a POST method and not allowed by default.

Comment: Yup, thanks for the input @S3DEV. OP, this should fix the problem. By default, Flask only allows `GET`, but since we are now passing `text` as an argument to be rendered, this is a `POST` method, which has to be specified in the route declaration.

Comment: The error has gone now but after the button click nothing happens

Comment: Can you try editing the form portion of `index.html` to `<form action="/stat" method="post">`?

Comment: I changed the div tag like this: `<div>{{ text }}</div>`and it works. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You want this initiated from the button right?  Here's how to achieve that with ajax...

```
<body>
<form action="/stat/">
<button type="submit" onclick="GetData();" id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">check stat</button>
</form>
<div id="stat_content"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetData() {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {   // XMLHttpRequest.DONE == 4
       if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           document.getElementById("stat_content").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
           else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
              alert('There was an error 400');
           }
           else {
               alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
           }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/stat/", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Valid point, however OP is using Flask.  AJAX is not needed.

Comment: Nothing happens after clicking in the button

Answer (score 0):

to update the content of that div, i think (based on your logic) you need to perform an ajax call to your `stat` function with the two parameters a and b submitted via `POST` request:

```
<form class="form-stat needs-validation" novalidate role="form">

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="a" value="">
    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="b" value="">
    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">check stat</button>

</form>

<div id="stat_content">Output: ?</div>
```

put the javascript code below after `jquery` call

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";

  $('.form-stat').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: "{{ url_for('stat') }}",
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $('.form-stat').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        // console.log(data);
        $('.form-stat input[name=a]').val(''); // reset field
        $('.form-stat input[name=b]').val(''); // reset field
        $('#stat_content').html(data); // update div with the returned vlue
      }
    });
  });
 
});
</script>
```

and you have to make little change to your `stat` function so you can submit dynamically the two parameters via `POST` like so :

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response
import json

@app.route('/stat', methods=['POST'])
def stat():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a = request.form['a']
        b = request.form['b']
        # check if inputs are valid to work with ..
        res = str(a) + ' is not ' + str(b) if a != b else str(a) + ' and ' + str(b) + ' are equal.'
        resp = make_response(json.dumps(res))
        resp.status_code = 200
        return resp
```

Comment: the html code gives me 29 Problems ;). anyway, the python function is just a placeholder,  it's not necessary to submit the 2 variables to the html

Comment: yes, it's clear the python function is just a placeholder but the logic is here: performing an ajax request. is that the right approach for your case or i'm miss understanding your concern ? what kind of problems ?

Comment: @MarkT i fixed my code little bit and it works as expected with simple Flask app
i was missing quotes in `url: "{{ url_for('stat') }}",` 
and mixed between python comments `#` and javascript commants `//`

Comment: It apparently sends the two variables from the input forms but the output stays without result.

Comment: @MarkT i have no clue, but make sure to call the javascript code above after the jquery obviously and try to uncomment `// console.log(data);`,  is there any kind of error ?

Comment: Maybe I don't down what you mean with query. In the body tag in the index.html  i have now the <forms>..., below, after the body tag, i have <script>...., correct?

Comment: if you uncomment `// console.log(data)` you should get the returned output from ajax call for e.g `2 is not 10`.

Comment: I solved it now, the solution was very close to Jake Tae's